# Finding possible friendship with recursion

Tags: c#, recursion, graph

I have a graph with friend relations:
[image]

For example Arnold knows Martha, Martha knows Arnold. Additionally, I have a file with friendships to check:

```
Arnold Martha (as in check if Arnold can know Martha trough mutual friends)
Amelia Rudolph
Ned Anthony
```

With these 3 checks there should be 3 possible outputs:

```
Arnold Martha => Arnold and Martha are friends
Amelia Rudolph => Impossible relation
Ned Anthony => Ned can become friends with Anthony via Mary
```

I've tried writing some code but can't quite wrap my head around it. How should I approach this using recursion with C#?

Comment: I think this would be to hard to start with if you cannot come up with something.

Comment: Wouldn't a simple dfs do the job?

Comment: So break it into pieces.  First, you need some code that given a starting point will list all of the possible folks knowable by a person.  That is start at a node, iterate over all the possible friends, then do the next level for those friends.  (Watch out for infinite loops.)  Once you have that module only then consider your original problem.  You get the list for the first person and then get the list for the second person and using the two lists you can decide the relationship.  I've deliberately left things a little obscure.  If you post some code, we can help you work on any issues.